# Why PHImageManager.default().requestImage returns " cropped " image when resize mode is .exact and target size is 5% of original Image size?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image-resizing, ios13

My requirement is to resize original image to 5% of its original size without crop. say image is (1000x1000) , resized image should be (50x50).

attached snippet below to help you understand structure of my process. 
thank you

note: i don't wanna use CGContext because i have tons of images to resize in few time

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagerequestoptionsresizemode/exact

as per documentation i am using .exact resize mode and i get 50x50 image but with center cropped

```
    // Asset has original image with (1000x1000)
   // imageSize is CGSize(width:50,height:50)

 let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
     options.resizeMode = .exact
   //options.normalizedCropRect = CGRect.zero
     options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
     options.isSynchronous = true
     options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: imageSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options, resultHandler: {(resultImage, info) in

// resultImage.size is (50x50) with centerCropped
})
```

Comment: Delete `options.isSynchronous = true`. Does that fix it? Or change mode to aspectFit. Does that help?

Comment: Also what does “with center cropped” mean? Could you post a picture of the result?

Comment: yes that both synchronous false and content mode aspect fit combinely worked for me. thank you @matt for saving time.